# Declaring objects inside or outside function

Tags: java, json, optimization

I have a function which parses JSON responses from an endpoint. I call this function with about 20k different inputs. Something like this:

```
for (Input input: inputList) {
    // We create a new getRequest with the query
    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(input.getUrl());

    // We make the getRequest accept application/json data
    getRequest.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray parsedArray = new JSONArray();

    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
    InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

    parsedArray = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"));

    parsedArrays.add(parsedArray);
    response.close();
}
```

I'm using `json-simple`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

At this moment I'm declaring the JSONParser inside the loop and I'm thinking about if it'll be better declaring it just outside it.

Is it better do declare the parser just one time and then pass it to the function like a parameter or the JVM already optimises this kind of things?

Comment: the answer is: *yes. or no. maybe. it depends.* a) without specific usage (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) saying anything would be just guessing, b) do a memory & CPU profiling to figure it out; no proper performance optimization for actual can be done only in theory, c) if you're creating an object with `new`, performance-wise for 20k executions/creations it's better to instantiate it only once *if the object is heavy and if its state is mutable & the object reusable within reasonable bounds*. Otherwise, 20k instances is just a breeze, unless it's done 100x per sec. "premature op" etc.

Comment: That might depend on how much it costs to create a new JSONParser instance and how big such an instance can get. But as long as there is enough memory the JVM might decide to grow the heap and collect unused (and not referenced anymore) objects only when it starts to run out of memory.

Comment: Please show your Parser. How big/complex are the JSON? Please provide an example.

Comment: @vaxquis I've edited the question with some more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends if you call the method from different threads. In that case if JSONParser isn't thread safe, there could be synchronization problems and it will be probably better to instantiate JSONParser in the method.

If you have just one thread, you can pass the JSONParser as method parameter.

But i guess the heap grows because of input data not just JSONParser objects.

The garbage collector is mostly activated (in HotSpot) when the heap is full, so it can just take more time until the gc is activated.

If you need to save time when new object is allocated (`new`, `invokespecial` and constructors instructions), then you should care about this, but in that case you need to think about every single object creation and for this there are other languages :). Just let JVM do its work :).

Comment: if the method is executed in more threads concurrently and the JSONParser isn't explicitly implemented as thread safe, than without some improvements of your code in term of synchronization you shouldn't, but it is hard to say without any code example

Answer (score 1):

Reusing objects like parsers is always a good idea. Even if the object's memory qualifies for garbage collection as soon as you're leaving the method and with that their scope, there's no guarantee that this is done instantly (VM decides), or even ever (in case the parser stows a reference to itself for example in a static list somewhere). So this might be the reason why you see increasing heap usage. In any case, you're doing the VM no favor.

The other side is speed. Each time you construct a parser, some kind of Grammar will be prepared for you. And this is the same on each construction. In the products I supervise, we make heavy use of JAXB and the necessary JAXBContext objects are instantiated lazy and also kept around to be reused, instead of reconstructed for each usage, because they are big and expensive to construct from the supplied class trees that make up the grammar.

Reusing a parser is usually possible, but sometimes it carries state or is not thread-safe, both of which are indicators that it might be problematic to reuse. The documentation of the parser class will tell you more.

Sometimes a parser is made up of two parts - for example the JDK regex implementation uses a Pattern object which is reusable and constitutes the grammar of the "parser", and a Matcher object which is the actual parser, is bound to a specific input and will carry state associated with that very input. Matchers are not reusable and must be recreated for each input, but the grammar itself, the Pattern, can be reused across the board.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer vaxquis was mentioning.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write. When I upvoted his _comment_ right after reading the question, it was shorter and has been edited 4 times since then :)

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu yup. You've just been a victim of an ugly case of user-induced comment rot *chuckle*. Still, seriously & frankly: I have the same problems with the comment system on SO as many people already outlined on meta - a) they aren't good for extended discussion, b) they are volatile and have no versioning, c) they deprecate quickly. OTOH, they are, well, as you pointed out, *comments* - still, there's no other feature (chat doesn't count here for many reasons) that allow direct communication outside of putting the data in Q/A (and that's frowned upon for obvious reasons).